# GOLANG: Why does SetDeadline/SetReadDeadline/SetWriteDeadline not work on a file when using os.File.Fd()?

Tags: go, unix, select, polling, epoll

I am using a combination of `os.File.SetReadDeadline` and `os.File.ReadFull`. But even if using `SetReadDeadline`, the deadline I have set is completely ignored and `ReadFull` blocks forever. Why is that?

Additional info: I fire some IOCTLS towards the file and therefore need os.File.Fd() to get the file descriptor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR:

Use `syscall.SetNonblock(fd.Fd(), true)` on the file after having used `os.File.Fd()`

---

This is due to the implementation of `read` [in golang UNIX](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.4:src/internal/poll/fd_unix.go;l=143):

```
func (fd *FD) Read(p []byte) (int, error) {
    if err := fd.readLock(); err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    defer fd.readUnlock()
    if len(p) == 0 {
        // If the caller wanted a zero byte read, return immediately
        // without trying (but after acquiring the readLock).
        // Otherwise syscall.Read returns 0, nil which looks like
        // io.EOF.
        // TODO(bradfitz): make it wait for readability? (Issue 15735)
        return 0, nil
    }
    if err := fd.pd.prepareRead(fd.isFile); err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    if fd.IsStream && len(p) > maxRW {
        p = p[:maxRW]
    }
    for {
        n, err := ignoringEINTRIO(syscall.Read, fd.Sysfd, p)
        if err != nil {
            n = 0
            if err == syscall.EAGAIN && fd.pd.pollable() {
                if err = fd.pd.waitRead(fd.isFile); err == nil {
                    continue
                }
            }
        }
        err = fd.eofError(n, err)
        return n, err
    }
}
```

The first `n, err := ignoringEINTRIO(syscall.Read, fd.Sysfd, p)` blocks forever if the file is set to blocking mode. `waitRead` is only executed if the file is opened in non-blocking mode. But I did open the file in non-blocking mode, so what happened?

The Implementation of `os.File.Fd()` [broke it](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.4:src/os/file_unix.go;l=75):

```
func (f *File) Fd() uintptr {
    if f == nil {
        return ^(uintptr(0))
    }

    // If we put the file descriptor into nonblocking mode,
    // then set it to blocking mode before we return it,
    // because historically we have always returned a descriptor
    // opened in blocking mode. The File will continue to work,
    // but any blocking operation will tie up a thread.
    if f.nonblock {
        f.pfd.SetBlocking()
    }

    return uintptr(f.pfd.Sysfd)
}
```

`Fd()` always sets the file to blocking. So we have to undo that before expecting polling reads. Therefore:

Use `syscall.SetNonblock(fd.Fd(), true)` on the file after having used `os.File.Fd()`